# Only returning selected features on shapefile from ArcPy cursor?

Tags: arcpy

I'm trying to only return information on a selected feature in a shapefile. According to other answers online, searchcursors should only act on selected features, but for whatever reason it's providing me with all the features in the shapefile.

Here's a basic example of what I'm working with:

```
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile):
    print row.TEXT
```

This code prints the output from the "TEXT" field for all features, not only the one I have selected.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include your ArcGIS version and more of your code, including the definition of `shapefile`.

Comment: How are you selecting the features?

Comment: Can you post your entire code? I can't reproduce the problem using the snippet you've provided (i.e. select features, run your code, returns only selected features).

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to making a selection, with a [SearchCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) you have the option to use the **where_clause** parameter, which will limit the records returned.

See [Building a Query Expression](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of opening the SearchCursor on the whole shapefile you could open it on a layer that has that shapefile as its data source.

Any selections (spatial and/or attribute) on that layer will be respected by the cursor.